# Outputting A Sentence Configured Via Random Pieces Using Pointer Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, random

I am new to coding and we're just learning pointers, and I'm unsure of why this code is not storing the bits of the sentence to the sentence array throughout the program, or why it is not able to print the data,

This is for a school assignment, and I normally just spend hours attempting different methods, but I figure it will be better to ask for advice so i can learn to do this correctly.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "string.h"
#define SIZE 4

void nounPick(const const char *nPTR, char *sPTR );
void verbPick(const const char *vPTR, char *sPTR );
void prepPick(const const char *pPTR, char *sPTR );
void artiPick(const const char *aPTR, char *sPTR );

int main(void){

   char *noun[SIZE];
   char *verb[SIZE];
   char *prep[SIZE];
   char *arti[SIZE];
   char *sent[SIZE];

   noun[0] = "cat ";
   noun[1] = "dog ";
   noun[2] = "truck ";
   noun[3] = "plane ";
   noun[4] = "skateboard ";

   verb[0] = "drove ";
   verb[1] = "jumped ";
   verb[2] = "ran ";
   verb[3] = "walked ";
   verb[4] = "flew ";

   prep[0] = "to ";
   prep[1] = "from ";
   prep[2] = "over ";
   prep[3] = "under ";
   prep[4] = "on ";

   arti[0] = "a ";
   arti[1] = "one ";
   arti[2] = "some ";
   arti[3] = "any ";

   const char *nPTR = noun[0];
   const char *vPTR = verb[0];
   const char *pPTR = prep[0];
   const char *aPTR = arti[0];
   char *sPTR = sent[0];

   srand( time(NULL));
   for(int c = 0; c< SIZE; c++)
        *(sent + c) = 0;

   nounPick(nPTR, sPTR);
   verbPick(vPTR, sPTR);
   prepPick(pPTR, sPTR);
   artiPick(aPTR, sPTR);

   printf("Made it through the picking\n");
   printf("Your Random Sentence Is As Follows:\n");

   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(*(sent + i) == 0)
            i = SIZE;
        else
            printf("%s", *(sent + i));
   }

   return 0;
}

void nounPick(const const char *nPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(nPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
}

void verbPick(const const char *vPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(vPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
}

void prepPick(const const char *pPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(pPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", sPTR);
}

void artiPick(const const char *aPTR, char *sPTR ){

    int i = 0;
    int l = rand() % 5;
    printf("%d, is L\n", l);

    do{
            switch(*(sPTR + i)){
                case 0:
                *(sPTR + i) = *(aPTR + l);
                break;

                default:
                i++;
                break;
            }
    } while (i < SIZE);
}
```

Comment: First observation is that `#define SIZE 4` means that you can't allocate `5` elements of those arrays.

Comment: And what is this `const const char *` which the compiler complains about (as well as other things). Pay attention to the compiler before dumping.

Comment: `sent` isn't initialized, is it? But you access it, e.g. in `if(*(sent + i) == 0) ...`

Comment: @WeatherVane I just saw that (in regards to const const) a few minutes ago and wanted to slap myself, I have fallen susceptible to tunnel vision and overlooked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers you're setting up (`nPTR`, `vPTR`, etc.) don't point to where you think they do.  For example, `nPTR` contains the value of the first element of `noun`, which is the address of the string `"cat "`.  It doesn't point to the array as you seem to think it does.  The same goes for the other pointers with similar names.

Those extra pointers aren't needed.  Just pass the arrays in question to your functions directly, and change them to accept parameters of type `char *[]`.

Your "pick" functions are all identical, so you don't need 4 of them.  You only need one that you pass different parameters to.

Getting to the functions, have an infinite loop.  When you assign a value to your sentence array, you don't increment `i`, and the `break` only gets out of the `switch` but not the `do ... while`.  Change the `switch` to an `if` and then use `break` when you do the assignment.  Your random number selection should also be mod'ing by `SIZE`, i.e. 4, instead of 5, otherwise you read off the end of the array.

Also, you're setting more elements in your word arrays then are available.  If the size is 4, you shouldn't be trying to set up 5 values.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'll try implementing  the suggestions and debugging now; I can't believe I overlooked the functions being the same, I guess i was too fixated on the other issues to see it.

Comment: @Jhall77 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @Jhall77 there is a checkbox that you can click.